# Where is the Custom Challenge Editor?

Tags: ryse-son-of-rome

In Ryse: Son of Rome, where is the Custom Challenge Editor and how do we access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Challenge Editor is not yet available. It will (or so the developers say) be added in a future update.